# how to add dynamically nodes to pane in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I want to add dynamically labels to a pane :

```
for (int k = 0; k < traitement.quad.lqua.size(); k++) 
{
  Label l = new Label();
  l.setText(traitement.quad.lqua.get(k));
  apane.getChildren().add(l);
}
```

here is the result : 
[image]

i don't want to have them in the same place i want to have one label by ligne , so where is the issue ?

Comment: What is the type of `apane`?

Comment: And the `AnchorPane` is the white area where the labels are added? Is there anything else, that will be added to that pane?

Comment: yes it's the white area .. no i want to add just labels

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `AnchorPane` with a `VBox`. That way all the labels will be added one below another.

`AnchorPane` manages the layouting of the children according to the anchor, which in your case seems to be top left. This works well if there is only one child, but will result in a mess if there are more.

In my personal experience I find `AnchorPane` not very useful when it comes to designing complex user interface. I usually en up using a `Group` or `Pane` instead and handle the layouting myself.

Comment: i have an exception : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException in this ligne : apane.getChildren().add(l);

Comment: That is probably because `apane` is not initialized before adding the child node.

Comment: no this is not the probleme i have try to add in fxml code a label it's shown by the one that i have add dynamically does not appear